# Using data to produce scatterplot with d3 transition method

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, transition, scatter-plot

I'm trying to do something like this: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nations/

However instead of the transitions on mouseover I want the transitions to display when I click on a button for each year in the timeline.

Some example data in a csv file:

```
time,name,xAxis,yAxis,radius,color
1990,America,10,20.2,30,black
1990,China,50,50,50,yellow
2000,Singapore,20,30,20,red
2010,China,60,50,50,yellow
2020,America,20,30,40,black
2020,Malaysia,60,5,10,orange
```

I'm new to javascript and d3 and am having trouble with the transitions. I want the circles to be unique to each name (America, China, Singapore, Malaysia) so that I will only have one circle per name. Currently new circles add when I click on the respective timeline buttons, but don't transit to new positions or exit.

Read data using d3.csv:

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(dataset) {
    var years = [];
    data=dataset;

    //create a button for each year in the timeline
    dataset.forEach(function(d){
        console.log(d.time);

        //if not existing button for timeline
        if($.inArray(d.time, years) == -1)
        {
            var button = document.createElement("button");
            button.setAttribute("type", "button"); 
            button.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-default");
            button.setAttribute('onclick', 'update("'+d.time+'")');
            var t = document.createTextNode(d.time);
            button.appendChild(t);
            $("#timeline").append(button);
            years.push(d.time);
        }
    })

    //create circles for the first year 
    svg.selectAll("circles")
        .data(dataset.filter(function(d) { return d.time == d3.min(years);}, function(d) { return d.name; }))
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        //.filter(function(d){ return d.time == d3.min(years); })
        .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.xAxis *10; })
        .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.yAxis; })
        .style("fill", function(d) { return d.color; })
        .transition()
        .duration(800)
        .attr("r", function(d) { return d.radius});
});
```

My update function:

```
function update(year){
    var circle = svg.selectAll("circles")
                .data(data.filter(function(d){return d.time == year;}), function(d) { return d.name; });

    //update
    circle.attr("class", "update")
        .filter(function(d){ return d.time == year; })
        .transition()
        .duration(800)
        .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.xAxis *10; })
        .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.yAxis; })
        .attr("r", function(d) { return d.radius});


    //enter
    circle.enter().append("circle")
            .filter(function(d){ return d.time == year; })
            .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.xAxis *10; })
            .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.yAxis; })
            .style("fill", function(d) { return d.color; })
            .attr("r", function(d) { return d.radius});

    //exit
    circle.exit()
        .remove();
}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`svg.selectAll("circles")` is invalid and should become `svg.selectAll("circle")` (singularize "circles").

As you have it currently, with `"circles"`, it yields an empty selection, so d3 assumes all your data is bound to non-existent circles, and therefore the `.enter()` selection is always full (rather than being full only at the first render).

Next, in the section labled `//update`, you shouldn't need to do any filtering. The `.data()` binding you're doing to a filtered array should take care of this for you.

Also, the section labeled `//create circles for the first year` is unnecessary, and probably should be removed to eliminate side effect bugs. The `update()` function, assuming it's working fine, should take care of this for you.